# Typescript call signature on function as argument

Tags: typescript, function, call

I am trying to build a function `defaultArguments` which takes an existing function and changes its default arguments with new inputs.

```
var add = function (a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
};

var defaultArguments = function(
    // func: (args: ReturnType<typeof func.arguments>) => void, 
    func: Function,
    obj: Object) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let alphabeth = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    if (typeof func === "function") {
        for (let i: number = 0; i < func.arguments.length; i++) {
            for (let a = 0; a < keys.length; a++) {
                // Replace arguments according to alphabethic order
                let arr = [];
                arr.splice(alphabeth.indexOf(keys[a]), 0, keys[a]); // push value to position of letter in 'alphabeth'
                func.arguments[a] = arr[a];
            }
        }
        return func;

    } else { return "Cannot find function " + func['name'] };
};

const add2 = defaultArguments(add, { b: 9 });
console.assert(add2(10) === 19);
console.assert(add2(10, 7) === 17);
console.assert(isNaN(add2()));
```

When calling the second command `console.assert(add2(10) === 19)` it gives me the following error:

`Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | Function' has no compatible call signatures`

As if the ReturnType of `const add2 = defaultArguments(add, { b: 9 })` is not a function of a string.

Comment: The quick answer is because `defaultArguments()` returns either a `Function` or a `string`.  You have `else return "Cannot"...`, so the compiler thinks it might return a string.  You should probably `throw` instead of `return` in such an error condition.

Comment: After you fix that, though, you still just have a `Function`, which really isn't type safe (it will accept all arguments and return `any`).  I don't really know the best way to type such an unusual function; the returned function accepts some kind of optional arguments although the position of those arguments depends on the keys of `obj` in a weird way.  But you didn't ask, so I guess I won't try.  

Answer (score 1):

As @jcalz points out in the comment, the method `defaultArguments` either returns a `function` or a `string`.

At the point where you write the code...

```
console.assert(add2(10) === 19);
```

the compiler quite rightly flags an error, because at this point you do not know which of the two possible types `add2` is.

If you add an additional type check to your code, the compiler will be assured you are working with a value of type `function`, and will compile without an error.

```
if (typeof(add2) === 'function')) {
  console.assert(add2(10) === 19);
  console.assert(add2(10, 7) === 17);
  console.assert(isNaN(add2()));
} else {
  console.error(add2);
}
```

Comment: That works! Now, non related to this, the compiler throws an other error: 

`throw e;
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at defaultArguments (/Users/luca/Desktop/splyt-tasks/splyt-test.js:12:44)`

Apparently it cannot seem to be able to read the property `arguments` of `func`, hence "null" in the error. Am I missing something? How do I scope the arguments array of the function argument?